# Why is this corollary a corollary? (Field extensions and symmetric polynomials.)

Tags: field-theory, symmetric-polynomials

In Stewart and Tall's book on Algebraic Number Theory, they give a theorem of Newton:

**Theorem 1.12.** Let $R$ be a ring.  Then every symmetric polynomial in $R[t_1, \ldots, t_n]$ is expressible as a polynomial with coefficients in $R$ in the elementary symmetric polynomials $s_1, \ldots, s_n$.

After proving this they give the following corollary.

**Corollary 1.14.** Suppose that $L$ is an extension of the field $K$, $p \in K[t]$, $\partial p = n$, and the zeros of $p$ are $\theta_1, \ldots, \theta_n \in L$. If $h(t_1,\ldots,t_n) \in K[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$ is symmetric, then $h(\theta_1, ..., \theta_n) \in K$.

Note: $\partial p$ denotes the degree of polynomial $p$.

**My Question**: I don't see how the corollary follows from the theorem in any straightforward way.  Surely the way to apply the theorem is to first consider any symmetric polynomial $h(t_1,\ldots,t_n) \in K[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$ and then rewrite $h$ in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials according to theorem 1.12.  But I don't see why evaluating these elementary symmetric polynomials at roots $\theta_1,\ldots, \theta_n$ should always yield something in $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) hold in any field.

Comment: Vieta's formulas are not mentioned directly or otherwise in this introductory text.  Although Vieta certainly closes the gap I was looking for, I'm wondering if there is some simple explanation I'm overlooking.

Comment: @Fixee: The formulas are so ubiquitous they sometimes aren't even named, just taken for granted. The explanation is rather simple: expand $a_n(T-\theta_1)(T-\theta_2)\cdots(T-\theta_n)$ and you will find the coefficients of $p(T)$ as alternating elementary symmetric polynomials in the $\theta_i$'s.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The coefficient of $t^i$ in $p(t)$ is $(-1)^{n-i}a_ns_{n-i}(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)$ where $a_n$ is the coefficient of $t^n$ in $p(t)$.  So we know that $s_i(\theta_1,...,\theta_n)\in K$.

Comment: Far from a "hint", I think this completely answers the question.  (And it was essentially given in a comment by @anon below his answer.)